# Zoom like frame appeared. How to disable it?

Tags: xubuntu, 19.04

I don't know how accessibility like zoom feature have appeared. Maybe I have input some keys' combination. I don't know how to get rid of it.
I've tried to disable it in:

> Start menu -> Settings Manager -> Settings Editor -> xfwm4

unchecking `zoom_desktop` value, but this frame have not disappeared.

Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Which version of xubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu 19.04 with xfce4. I didn't find tag with 19.04 version

Comment: The issue had dis appeared by itself. Maybe, an update had influenced it. And now I use Budgie DM on 19.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I decided to record some screen area using **vokoscreen**. The same frame appeared.

It seems likely the frame in my question have been produced somehow by a **vokoscreen** without a **vokoscreen** being launched by me. Looks like it was a bug.

[image]

So I could get rid of it by `vokoscreen` launching and by switching to **Fullscreen** as I think.